# JSSOR Slider Centring Slider

Tags: slider, center, jssor

How am I able to centre the slider onto my webpage?

I have used the banner-rotator.source as is, just struggling to centre it onto the page.

Comment: Please add some source or a link so we can help!

Answer (score 0):

Use `margin: 0 auto;`, you can center everything.

See

```
<div id="slider1_container" style="... margin: 0 auto; ...
```